# It's a dog! (Or is it?)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, decision-problem

[The city defines a dog as any living entity with four legs and a tail.](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/f5ee7276-d66d-480a-862f-2f0dcfa5311e) So raccoons, bears, mountain lions, mice, [these are all just different sizes of dog.](https://www.danharmonsucks.com/shows/community/quotes/season-five/basic-story/)

Given an ASCII-art image of an animal, determine if that animal is a dog.

### Rules

An animal is a dog if it has four legs and a tail.

The foot of a leg starts with one of `\` (backslash), `|` (pipe), or `/` (slash), has one or more `_` in between, and another `\`, `|`, or `/`. Each foot will hit the last line of the string. The feet may not share a common border.

```
\ \  |   /   /    |  |     /  |   |  / /     <-- These are all just
|_|  |___|  |_____|  |_____|  |___|  |_|         different sizes of leg.
```

A tail is a line coming out of the left side of the figure and touching the leftmost part of the multiline string. The tail is made up of either `-` or `=` characters. The tail must be at least one character long, and can optionally end with a `o` or `*`.

```
o---  *--  *==  --  ==  -  =  o===  *-      <-- These are all just
                                                different sizes of tail.
```

You can take input as a multiline string, or array of lines. Output a truthy or falsy value to determine if the figure is a dog, or any two distinct values.

Truthy test cases:

```
      ______/\__/\
    _/    (  U U  )
*--/____. ,\_ w _/
    \  /| |\ |\ \
    /_/ \_/|_| \_\
```

```
    _________/\
o==/         ''>
   |_||_||_||_|
```

```
        /\__/\
       (  o O)
       /   m/ 
      |    |      don't ask
o-----|    \__
      |   ___ \_______
      //\ \  \___ ___ \
     /_/ \_\    /_|  \_|
```

Falsy test cases:

```
        __________          _
 ______/ ________ \________/o)<
(_______/        \__________/
```

```
     ____/)(\
    /   \o >o
   (     \_./
o--\ \_.  / 
    \____/
    ||  ||
    \/  \/
```

```
   /\/\/\/\/\
o-/       o.o
   /_/_/_/_/
```

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25507/)

Comment: Is an animal has 5 feet a dog?

Comment: [Are these dogs?](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fQUFBPwYVcuXr6isgg3y9fC6Qunh9ZMzFRZpeZIhVL1b9uM0g3xx0nyiQ7R6sYUIq0NeNASKQzngwgIgSxwa6UEtXAyIUAyL1FYhja8FdGgMxUZ8YNtf//wA)

Comment: Why is the last false case false?

Comment: @Jonah I assume it's because "the feet may not share a common border."

Comment: @tsh It must have exactly 4 legs. So in the ones you sent, the first, second, fourth, and last figures are dogs

Comment: @Jacob are there any restrictions on the connectedness of the figure?  eg, in tsh's first dog, the legs are not connected.  Could I have 4 free floating legs and a tail to the left of them, also free floating, and be a dog?

Comment: Is there any restriction on the height of the tail, e.g. is `-|_||_||_||_|` a dog?

Comment: Do the truthy test cases become falsy if you mix `-` and `=` signs in the tail?

Comment: @Neil `-|_||_||_||_|` is a dog, and no to the second question—forgot to remove that from the spec

Comment: Suggest adding a test case of a dog with five legs. That one really messed me up.

Comment: Are these dogs? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fAQjiUYB@THw8V76trb4CGshXcOECUjXo4voQ0RogigFxIUywYHwNECno6ulCmVxcME1w67igPIR1MUAnYHeDPsgRCjFYXBETrwDUBLUV4hSwXyBssBiSg8AAznbg@v8fAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: [Is this a dog?](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fAQriYYALytOHySjExOvHxAAl8m1tEYJgAOTmA@VBWmpQZWLiFYCaFGogUjVAFAPWAGGDxcBS8TVApKAbH68LYys46P//DwA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @chunes Yes, those are some very handsome dogs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>43</s> 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε„*oõš„-=âJÅ?}àIθ„__¬:.œε…\|/Sã'_ý¢O}à4Q*
```

Input as a list of lines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V/z/9zWRw3ztPIPbz26EMjQtT28yOtwq33t4QWe53YABeLjD62xOrzBW@/oZJDKZTE1@sGHF6vHH957aJE/UJVJoNb//wpgEA8G@jEgzAUW0AeRGgoKoUCooMmlpaurD1Kip6ATE69QDpQHK4tRUNCvUaiJASGIRn2gzph4/Zr4GiAVAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##vVTBahRBEL33VxR92d1he@riKbjZHLzoJYp4a2giWWQQt0N2VBY6EBC/wLuYCIIo3rKI4mWGXPMR@ZG1qnu6Z3Y3IeYQq7tnqqurql9VzZSd7T0vJksnq4WsTt7Ix4eTspyrg8NiWk72oZgevC63QA7n1e@hkA9nUJSwB/v2xRjkeF59XV6cXR5/zGx9dn5CjBrVp4/q9@Oj@lP14@InSYypvm9dHn/RzlS/6nf5@Qe2oC0@rT/3TP2nOt0l7XtPsmUh55OZrL/JqZVHw2oxXoIn4wk1L@EFyM8@wDMaMBCZUsgqOQy1gbd07tU0ADpwmmcwRLLUBp1x9NKiWojWv79C2NEIIVKvt80KpJ5mtPHeWkQBjoXdQdyyl1cIzdalB1Dypj1K4uylsIrJi8lVR5WwsMRTI0bUHBBLw3GQh4h0YB2fr0BMoZkUFJDHJtx0nC4zaAf3RT9uoolu/WBy73eDfpNZ1rKwbUVIhTfKkUPUzLGGSK5CfZzjFaTIq3GNOg4yjxhs7l1TvGFs6G5YrNt11@2tu@Ma6ys9XI@hg@O2hErTFKnA3WLfxBPGTPU7ZQ@fwc18JtY@B/wXniNUd/gHjWjc1R9kVojBrvaHWF54IFpwnSoFqfM9KPQimm1HAZUr2ExKujBiaC@k3qWvRoEMI4S0hoM6Ihk19wYwPprAe1kHUkhg5Hf@Ly5os7SOSxmjEq4d/As). (NOTE: I've added a remove spaces `ðK` before the partition builtin, to speed it up significantly. So should you test a 'dog' which has a space in one of its feet (e.g. `|_ |`, the `ðK` should be removed to test it properly.)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Validate the tail:

```python
ε              # Map over each line of the (implicit) input-list:
 „*o           #  Push string "*o"
    õš         #  Convert it to a list of characters and append an empty string:
               #   ["*","o",""]
      „-=      #  Push string "-="
         â     #  Get all combinations of the two with the cartesian product:
               #   [["","-"],["","="],["*","-"],["*","="],["o","-"],["o","="]]
          J    #  Join each inner pair together to a string:
               #   ["-","=","*-","*=","o-","o="]
           Å?  #  Check for each whether the current line starts with it
}à             # After the map: pop and push the maximum to check if any was truthy
```

Step 2: Validate the feet:

```python
I              # Push the input-list again
 θ             # Leave just its last line
  „__          # Push string "__"
     ¬         # Push its first character (without popping): "_"
      :        # Keep replacing all "__" with "_" until there are no "__" left
.œ             # Get all partitions of this string
  ε            # Map over each partition:
   …\|/S       #  Push triplet-list ["\","|","/"]
        ã      #  Get all pairs with the cartesian power of 2:
               #   [["\","\"],["\","|"],["\","/"],["|","\"],["|","|"],["|","/"],["/","\"],["/","|"],["/","/"]]
         '_ý  '#  Join each inner pair with "_" delimiter:
               #   ["\_\","\_|","\_/","|_\","|_|","|_/","/_\","/_|","/_/"]
            ¢  #  Count how many times each foot occurs in the parts
             O #  Sum the counts of each type of foot together
  }à           # After the map: pop and leave the maximum sum of counts
    4Q         # Check if this is equal to 4
```

Step 3: Combine the checks and output:

```python
*              # Multiply the two checks together
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think finding all possible feet and tails would be shorter than a regex

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, I was surprised as well when I saw my answer was shorter than the Retina answer (or the JavaScript regex-based answer). :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 102 bytes

```python
lambda x:any(re.match("[\*o]?[\-=]+",r)for r in x)*len(re.split(r"[\\|/]_+[\\|/]",x[-1]))==5
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU5LCoMwEN17iiGrxKqhi0IphJ6iK0eCbQ0VNEqaUoXcpBuhtHfqbZqo83sw8x5vXt9-tLdOT28l8POwKt3_VFO252sJw6HUIzVV1pb2cqMkx7grjjmmotiQxDDVGTBQaxhY3FQ6MO99U1tqPBUdL-RmQZIMebotGBNiF9Vt3xkLplrdXG9qbanyKkJgDjkHx9DRvOBhUoCTT2BRLAQPlAwSlPD095mGANyBw1CLkHslSu6k84DgHdYXCWrCGFt-mKYF_w)

Takes in a list of lines.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 59 bytes

```
^((.*¶)*[*o][-=])?(.*¶)*(.*?[\\|/]_+[\\|/])*.*$
$#4$#1
^41$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVE7bsMwDN15CgJxEUutTQTIWCdH6FB0Mh21Q4cMrYCiQBedJ0fwAXwxl6QsO9SH4iP5SNo/n7/X7495GmG6wev7dBP1UIuGaZwvdd36aXS@93Hom25w5wUQde6ZEw3hMWvnW19BtTtWuwNcjodqntEkmBDrAQNI7xrxTRY68E1DGtLiEwf8E7@FMSIlTKw7J5JkcqAUkigG2NitAMSuIyyy3580QILXnTOMaesmtxLxxRVTOb4IFzPZBbFRMUNy73xSWhGTBSZi7V7R7M54bp/zM6n/rqN1jrBOgMK3zLa611KBonuGuhglhTceWsjt7erlE2pMxFOEPLeltKTjsb40Alai/CNS0pNR0mPExGVJcqkfWyOWSfP6Bw) Link is to test suite that splits on blank lines for convenience. Explanation:

```
^((.*¶)*[*o][-=])?(.*¶)*(.*?[\\|/]_+[\\|/])*.*$
```

Optionally match a tail, then match any number of legs.

```
$#4$#1
```

Replace with the count of legs and whether a tail was matched.

```
^41$
```

Check for exactly four legs and a tail.

Comment: Right tool for the job

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>62</s> 101 bytes

```
[ dup R/ ^[*o]?[-=]+/m re-contains? swap
"\n" split last R/ [\\|\/]_+[\\|\/]/ count-matches 4 = and ]
```

+39 bytes to disallow dogs with more than four legs. Ouch. :\

[image]

Comment: Love the names lol. They could have their own show or book or something together

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 77 bytes

Though it's using core tools, so should work on other shells.

Edit: 7 bytes saved because I was being brain dead about how to test in TIO. Thanks for the nudge, @Neil.

Edit: just added more test cases

```bash
grep -Eqo ^[o*]?[=-] $1&&[ `tail -1 $1|grep -Eo "[/\\|]_+[/\\|]"|wc -l` = 4 ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVRb06JIEn3nVxAbEx27U9GRIrciJmY2UBQUFFRUpGd2Ry4FIqCCFJft/e29fNPzMLEPRFUmVVmZJ8/J4Fqn34JrHUsC@zliv7JJUw63J/s5HPfva8V2lLCf2ekvEMUUyibPWe6XT1Mm@vs/2P98S6p4PLp4Pdh/fXn8@Ns/v/z8@Tf2B@7Tpy/s7@/rLWc/c6P59c9jD/ZvX@DXX7/@9m/0ff3b1zZkP@e/sz@zAvvbt/8y5FGx5JbH7K1k33H9/pH9iY0ebHh9sz/84R/NP3efPrFxmD7@tDRbZ79@/atna7sfzp@@@z7ClPE3Q6hXqt29helmrqJp5J4h3M8GPZ88VrWnJerdzFNxIWzNQlKq3rGCxakX6PFwP76D4/JYF3u/v77WB8t6M/79LU1nzm3Ha1mrlp3mpp1YHyKdi9HMtj3lLEXb9Vuv63hdTkNlSpaCX3F7xUgRBrIQ8HnAsb6pc2nLPJ77l3kspaBy1/xrcpbFfW/ubm6bq7lu29fj/Hq6Z9w8bvkHihd1Eb3ovWnzbRXKincpYqDrNlhK@4FmDI7kJ0WuaU1O0nJyooTOzvLkRRXu3O9jQVlv0X5X5L48nQbNgneCRcWTgQ/2ghA73nPnbzdnR6ET9@WZjI5pr8hhgTi5V@wynhq1VJK2de6J/a79Z7rHQJ3A8riId3fo5ULsLmVi9MQXpHfEG6esIpNLBe94zuBUFFUCnnU31lB046vdffq6qZvieu/kcrcLZ8fpMtZ5ix@mcTYTZUKJ0@RKb/rDNYgP3iXKKiHOfLlmnO1dms/9NS5ulTVx@ol2lRDcJvtbHcvYXgf5HmQZYpj0lyvFdL1wgBfcns9kW1xET6kIl4Q@h0ScUUZevWulwJtZKV67w4Z/iEk4jbf@@5LsyEQujkGVax4fbB6VEo8xgm5Z854v2gSGiKqwnbz6zEFc4sCMAaRBSgtiwxJ6gi2Y1pbazGAGnbN2N/FT6MzFvmrJhAilEslZ6aGn@DwhHqcLolSZA1l6GLAr@BpD8EIVnWrsXXk8iwnddhl3pCZcRyAP/esy2A7MqWCA4ICOfBBCF9YEUzDREg5BAigQvdbXY2lhM82uP803GvDxDI4xFjn6gjFtDwK0uzmY66ji84bgI4w16LZ9wNtdIQgrhXK3gJPRSt/LYTlT9k9LY2Ro3N31VU8N@XDIj3K1SK1N6i1pivKolQ8T2rXeUyb2I@tlrVWy91I/Qks98iQ3w0KaeD6I0NEx8TODR8bNCABWKlzKgTCRro6Zn5ul7VHFe3r5tN9BUsSGIPFv0fGR7cia0EhExFOXZkrGI35yrwCI2zDDeZ0knqEhkpOGzsHbyGCSjqIIqdDxrdNOJ8rTVUJYqroijBjR9q1tT1YyaP70g0bpw3e8ZaRHEybSMpNbxtTRKadKLy8LpfmeThXgygJw@gIBRKflB8LfndVcygC7fVwuyUPrwkc51O5wAemM6yj1R6E3XolWGn/DDvRNKZChBI/Xrx1gDrY4hvvYup7iShwEgktIycgaQRY8Xo1iXU92HbdbdQbIbQDMi6@c2g@guZZTmFg3KJUB1pCixtc3lw10JFk3rvcUh3C@eVU8aO7ckI7iWdqSRynFZQhuvibS9WJGjNVlIIlB64inq0h6KnjQOnCDC5E9l/agU3DAxMs7@k7kZDITd@VW20abcMx8C28yAuK8wYAl86JTuNsZFGgNDvfClr2hK3p3LbQFpxfjjX3LxRKyCcU5TJu3qxnQjZQbadwSxcHBWH4pvkyQjzsmdkRnhazUpGDtZvRp7iszUcPVyOLleBl1ppwT3q5BjrSj40JGHKhPSzU69G3RaP4Bu7CLPyTiANMSSEAKRIfXbjDxMBnrbHYWbCXdE2DMpg1TTSpnqqkG8CESQRyFCAjk8TELpKQ40gVBhhVvgXEP5fekB7IBaeGCCAvoKiwLA@jxSZ@lA@Y7A2moVjqlEgGTBnoDyaIGbtdq1HiEiWWoXRwBs895aeTOqIaEgPoh27Eh8t0uVwR0kpH1OBnMy@4sOIqNNVQ1142iAa6woVQowNJCuKnQY2mEIWMgUk5Qk4F85OegAkXwRhWqYAUlyNkdFK0xNy7Y43Sq3gScSwkbgso3acnIfpIsqA6IuwAXVcwQ3Gcf42VsTTM28CNQDtiAiiZw3FTurX6qGzNQQeETgkkF7TP9YMDEyoDvXKCSjHfnA0@q/MG09mOuNrSPin13kedd/dyrtHJVRPstKc5rleA6PnXnoc5APmXAwZOYj0p0Rt5hCwdQxjIUoxMPwITjsHsQvjFeUapvb1aYZOhDGjYnjxdfypRiKyUpWXXVRuALsb2cItFDpQSowZXiYwstPioZIdKZEaP1Hxjp2IQmEuA1Ri/CVOkS7pDN8wUBOnew7FHkhZz3BsGbY8DXSWBw468lX1qS27ny8bxzGHcVaP2zTZqh6TplU2Axdvaa3mVhgp3hwJ/FHdc7W//sXR46f93t9q2zLMvevFrThbqf/fVj/t9RSQao1/Zp3S9qr6oq8@1/)

Comment: Wouldn't this be 7 bytes shorter as a full program rather than a function?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.match(/[\\|\/]_+[\\|\/](?=.*$)|$/g)[4]</^[*o]?[-=]/m.test(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUvBDoIwDL3zFT2YsKGsHjyY6OTmDxhPFBeCAzHIFKZisn9HQF/7Xpv2vWv6StusKe82rM1Z97nsO7nrxC212YVhTOQIEzX/LyySIphxN8OCx6tki6c4MEkUhzLBm7C6tazj/cbLTN2aSovKFCxnjX48y0YzP299LhqdnvdlpQ@fOmPLhf@0@drnnPcwQU1AGulNBxyVARyHAu4FUuJoEbAgBe/hP9kIAB04GvsXxCFJCp1ywyD4Ag)

```javascript
'' < true
'' ≮ false
undefined ≮ true
'|_|' ≮ true
```

Comment: Why do you need this part `(?=.*$)|$` in the first regex?

Comment: Also, you can save one byte in the second regex: `/^[*o]?-|=/m`

Comment: @Jacob Make it at last line

Comment: @Jacob Fail `o=`

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 57 bytes

```bash
/^[o*]?[=-]/{t=1}END{exit t&&gsub(/[/\\|]_+[/\\|]/,0)==4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVRrD6JIFv3OrzCTSc@jtnNFXkV6ezcoigpKqajozOxGHgUiovIoHtP923tx@stkPxAqp1K3Tp17zvUuRfzNuxShLA4@BoMvg6jKuutz8NHv1@UlHzSMDj4O/gVByCCr0pQLfv5l8CdX@Pn1WX7@6Rv857fHr3/8@7fPH/@AP8vP/NfpWv8zbK7loPzwISoq72f4DX7//csf/0Xf//CP4S@fP4tfv/3EXerb4Icfv5f6gfvK0Uc@oNc0HFyzQRkW5a@fBsFj4F/KwY9v@NPg53/@tRgEvww@fBiEfvz4vjNY245uG4MvX/4OvpFP34F3oSz8NheLhWY3pThaTTQ0Cpwj@NtxZ6TDx6Jw9Ui7mWksTcW1eZfVvCWWNz20ItvvbvvS28/2xX17bi@v5c6ySu58K@XRmFw3gp7UWtboTtxIxS4w@BCNbdtVj3KwXpZGUYTLbOSrIzoTzzm/VecxwkCnIj52ODRWRSqvucdz@zL3mezlzlJ4DY@KtG3NzdWpUy01bPuyn1wOt4SfhLXwQOG0uAcvdqvqdJ37iuqe7iGwZe3N5G3HEg4HypMhx7SGB3k2PDDKxkdl@GIqf2y3oagu12i7uadnZTTyqqlAvGku0E7wtqIYEve5Oa9XR6KyofNyTc7ArFUV/454pVXtLBzNCzmjdU1ukV0W52e8xcCIZ7l8IDgb9HIgdGYKnbf0LMplIMwPSU6HpxzKcMLhWJI0Cq51my/h3vS3NrfR66qt7pdbo2SbjT/ej2ahIVhCNwqTsaRQRkmVqq157i5euHNPQZKLYXJWCo6sb/Jkcl7i@zW3hqQd6hcZwXW4vRahgu2ll25BUSCEYXu6MMyWUwKC6LRCotjSNHjKd39G2bOLpDHjlEVZqHe8GmfSpdmthIcU@aNwfS5P0YYOlfvey1PdFbzVI1fDvobXzArBPUs2hS5gGqyHrzYhiI8IjDlAOsTsTm2YQUuxBaPC0qoxjKEhS2cVPsXGnG7zmg6pmKmBkmQuekrPAxJwPKVqnhBI4l2HHfGscxRPNYnkfe@y/VGK2LpJ@D0z4dILuWtfp84mMGHiHEQCBjqD6DuwpJiBiWaw8yJAnuTWZyOUpzZXbdrDZKWDEI5hH2KJZy/oabvgoc2VYL5h6lmYi2eEsQ7NuvUEu7mL4kJl/NXjFbQwtoqfjdXt09I5BSpnc3kVo7my26V7JZ/G1ip2ZyxGaVAruyFravepUPuRtIpeq0k5M/ZQM5c@6XVuIV067iRoWE/8yOHecWMKgNUcZ4onDuULMdNjNbNdprpPNx21G4ju4VyUhVIiZ2QTRRcrmUp45LBETQQkDG85AHUqrjsuo8id64imtGITcFcKmLRhKEAaNEJN6tFQfTqqDzPNUMVeI1aX@vpgRZ1@Hr1tFD/OxJ0FRjDkAj0x@VnIiMF4TX65iS9PtmykAp/dAccvEEEitdBR4UYWEzkB7LRhNqMPvfEfWVc43QnkIy6C@NwHvXIztNCFKybQVplIuwxcwbg0gHlY4xBufetahnOpEynOIKa9a0RFdAUtCA0j2jT8ZtHMQak94F5CToqzB9UlG8HQukKmdrCEGFVnY3VaQUOjZeW4T6nzJ6tXLoDuTObyXjrKa/rI5DDzwUmXVL6czICzmgRkyauJdLhItGWiCzWBK5yo4jqsBYMBARPPbui7kaPhWNpka30drPye@RpK2gtCSpjDjHuxEdzsBO5oCYR/YctesQW7ORZaA2mlcGVfUymDZMhwCqOqdPQ5NL3lehvXVCXY65@fSS8TlP2GC4lEFsiKTQbWZsye5jY3I81f9C6e9YdRYyopFewClEDfEwcSSqA4zLRg19b3Sj/vsAOb8B0RAlxNIQLZk4igX2HoYtq/s9pYsJYNV4SeTe3HupyNNVPz4B0SUeqDCAiU/jIL5Oi@Z1OK5la4Bs7ZZd9Jd3QF8tQBCabQ5FgROzDCgzGOOyw0c6SjQm3UXAJMK2jnSJF0cJpaZ/OHH1lzrQkD4LapIPfe6dMQUdDese0botzsbEHBoAld9pPBPG2OIlFtrKO8uqxUHXCO52qOPCxPxasGLZZ7GRIOAvUABe3omx9BdxRAiXKUwwIyUJIbqHplrhyw@@mUlxTIKYMVRVlJa9q7n0ZTZgDiT8AHOdd5t/F7vPStqfoGvgulgOeQswj2q9y5Fk9tZXoaqEJEMc2hfsZvBwytBITGASYreHPcCTRPH1xtPyZaxdrgvm1OyqQpnluN5Y6GWLum9@NSo7gID82xKxJQDgnw8KTmI5dI7ztsYQ@yUIF7D@IOOL8fdg8qVPNXEBvrq@VHCXpHw@aV/uBLHTFsxTSmiyZficJdqk@HQHJRJgOqcK6esYWm75f0Ehlcr9HyL40MbEIViPDqq9/9WG0ifpdM0ikFNiFYcRlyfd4tQXQnGPBl6M35fmsmZJbsNI6yP24I5yw8vX3WUdVVTaOu7lgKyVY3msSPMOl2wlHa8C1Zn4/u6WEIl81mW5NZlrXmxRpNte347x/3/0Auz0G71E/rdtJaTdO4b/8D)